# C float assignment from literal

Tags: c, floating-point, assign

While reading part of a [book about 3D graphics](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Basics/Tut01%20Following%20the%20Data.html) I came across the following assignment:

```
const float vertexPositions[] = {
0.75f, 0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
-0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
};
```

Why is the f suffix necessary? Can the type of the literals not be determined from the type of the variable? I believe that without the f float literals are interpreted as doubles, but why when the array is clearly of type float?

Comment: I believe it's because of how the code is compiled, the compiler knows about the literals before knowing the array type.

Comment: Using GCC and no `f` I don't get any errors.

Comment: Still it is best practice to add `f`.

Comment: on some compilers, ASSERT(1.1 != 1.1f);

Comment: @franji1 That's on most compilers. You only need `float` to be IEEE 754 binary32 and `double` to be binary64, as they are almost everywhere. http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/11/08/Floating-point-quiz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The float array initialization in your example is fine in C, as it would be if it used `double` constants. For the values at hand, it would also be fine if it were a `double` array initialized with `float` constants, because the values at hand are exactly representable as `float`. There would be no reason for a compiler to emit a warning even in this last case, although it would be strange and confusing that the developer bothered to type additional suffixes that do not match the eventual type.

In short, the author is only being explicit, which, in the case of a `float` array, is good.

For arbitrary values written in decimal, you do not want to initialize `float` variables with `double` constants because of [“double-rounding”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding) (in which the word “double” means twice and does not refer to the type of the same name). If you initialize `f1` and `f2` as follows, they end up with different values, and `f1` is actually the closest to the intended value 1.01161128282547:

```
  float f1 = 1.01161128282547f;
  float f2 = 1.01161128282547;
```

The explanation is that in the case of `f2`, the decimal value 1.01161128282547 [is first rounded](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/11/08/Floating-point-quiz) to the nearest `double`, and then to the nearest `float`. These two steps introduce more error than directly rounding to the nearest `float`, which is how `f1` is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

1. Some terminological nitpicks.

   - This is not an *assignment*, it is an *initialization*.
   - What you have between the `{}` (e.g. `1.0f`) are not *literals*, they are *constants*. C only has *string literals* and *compound literals* and that's it. In C `1.0` is a floating-point *constant*.
2. In C language the type of the right-hand side (of an assignment or an initialization) is never influenced by the type of the left-hand side. The type of the value on the right-hand side is always determined independently. It is determined solely from how that value is specified. Left-hand side is never taken into consideration. Then, once the type of the right-hand size is known, the original value is *converted* to the type of the left-hand side. In other words, constant `1.0` is always a constant of type `double`, even if you use it to initialize a `float` object.
3. There's nothing incorrect with using a `double` constant (like `1.0`) to initialize an object of type `float`. As I said above, the `double` value will be converted to `float` type. However, some compilers issue a warning about that conversion, notifying the user about a possible precision loss. Specifically to subdue that warning people'd use an explicit float suffix (e.g. `1.0f`) or an explicit cast to `float` (e.g. `(float) 1.0`) when initializing `float` objects. This does not look good, since it goes against the DRY (Don't-Repeat-Yourself) rule, but in real life this method of dealing with warnings is encountered quite often.

Comment: Is initialization not just a type of assignment? I said assignment in my question because I thought it applies to all assignments, not just initialization.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the C standard does not use the word *literal* for floating-point constants.

Answer (score 0):

Although you may not get no errors for omitting the `f` it is good practice to put it and there are several reasons why, for example:

```
float num = 0.1;
(num == 0.1)
```

The evaluation will produce `0` because `num` is rounded to `0.1` as a float and `0.1` in the expression is double. So they are actually not the same, although they may seem to be.

Comment: note that in the evaluation below you get a promotion to double for `num` because you are comparing with double literal

Comment: @pqnet Not true. Try it out before you comment.

Comment: @Igor I can confirm that `num` is promoted to `double` in `(num == 0.1)`. Also, the expression `(num == 0.1f)` would evaluate to `1`, as expected. The problem in `float num = 0.1; (num == 0.1)` entirely lies with the comparison and `float num = 0.1f; (num == 0.1)` would produce exactly the same result.

Comment: It produces a zero, I swear. @PascalCuoq

Comment: @Igor Of course. Everyone involved in the discussion here knows that `(num == 0.1)` produces `0`. Neither pqnet nor I is arguing about that.

Comment: We get it, we are programmers, we do it for a living. @PascalCuoq

Comment: @Igor I wouldn't know how to "try it out", but it makes sense to me that you have to do the comparison either between two float or two doubles, because it does not makes sense to compare them as they are. If the opposite were true (i.e., the `0.0` being converted to float and comparison being executed in float) you would indeed get a 1 as result of the comparison, so I think you misunderstood us, we are actually saying the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood. We get it, we are programmers, we do it for a living. If there were no mistakes we would be out of jobs. @pqnet

Answer (score 0):

No, type of literal is never inferred. Without the `f` they are `double` literals, and the instruction is a conversion which may lose precision (not really in this case because all the literals are exactly represented with float too).

Same warning you get if you do

```
float x = 3.0;
```

Comment: On my compiler (gcc) float x = 3.0 produces no error

Comment: The transformation that takes place in `float x = 3.0;` is called a *conversion*. A *cast* is an explicit syntactic construct that causes a conversion. There is a cast in `float x = (float) 3.0;`, but there isn't in `float x = 3.0;` (there is a conversion).

Comment: it is not an error, but some compiler will warn you that it is an implicit cast that may lose precision

Comment: @PascalCuoq ok I guess I used the wrong word. I heard a lot about the "implicit cast" term, but it was always used improperly I guess

Comment: There's no such thing as an "implicit cast". BTW, in this case the literals are represented exactly if `FLT_RADIX` is a power of 2 or of 10 -- which it almost certainly is (in fact `FLT_RADIX != 2` is rare).

Comment: @KeithThompson I admit it was my error on writing implicit cast. I know that `3.0` has an exact representation in float (actually, it is true for any `FLT_RADIX % 2 = 0` or `FLT_RADIX % 3 = 0`, not only for power of two or ten), but that wasn't my point. My point was that there is an implicit conversion from a type to another to another, since the type for `3.0` is a 64-bit float while the type for `x` is a 32-bit float, and that would trigger a warning from many compilers.

Comment: @pqnet: The type of `3.0` is `double` (which is often 64 bits, but that's not guaranteed). The type of `3.0f` is `float` (which is often 32 bits, but that's also not guaranteed). `double` and `float` (as well as `long double`) are *floating-point types*.

Comment: if you only want to troll by being picky on names keep going, you are not adding information. I'm out of this conversation