# Double constants usage with suffix 'f'

Tags: c, floating-point, double

```
double f_64  = 3.35f;
double f1_64 = 3.35;
```

What is the effect if suffix 'f' is used?

With the online FPU compilers, hexadecimal results are as below

With suffix `f` - `0x400ACCCCC0000000`, 
without suffix `f` - `0x400ACCCCCCCCCCCD`.

Comment: ["f" after number/float in Objective-C/C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2391818/995714), [Is there a functional difference between "2.00" and "2.00f"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7697148/995714), [C float assignment from literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25209576/995714), [Purpose of a ".f" appended to a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4828167/995714)

Answer (score 1):

The `f` suffix forces the compiler to treat the value as `float` as opposed to a `double` which in the below assignment doesn't make much sense.

```
double f_64 = 3.35f;  
// Why force a value to float when you've allocated memory for a double
```

Remember that `double` [is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2386882/1620779) is 2X the precision of `float`. Choose the type as per your specific needs.

But, say,you're doing

```
float ans;
ans = 3/2; // ans is trimmed to an int
ans = 3/2.0f; // The decimals are retained
```

Comment: There may be very rare situations in which one wants a double initialized with the value that would have resulted from initializing a float to 3.35f, perhaps for comparison to a float.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I agree  to what you pointed out.